# In Tyrian full game mode, is there any benefit to buying the SuperCarrot ship?

Tags: tyrian

I'm playing Tyrian single player full game and am somewhere in Episode 2. I have two ship upgrades possible: MicroCorp Stalker-B for 25000 or SuperCarrot for 65000. The SuperCarrot has less armor than the Stalker-B, though... is there any benefit to getting the SuperCarrot other than it being awesome to fly around in a big carrot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep!  They each have different [super weapons](http://members.iinet.net.au/~vannevar/tyrian/suprtwid.html).

In this case, the MicroCorp Stalker-B comes equipped with:

- Repulsors
- Mine Spray

The SuperCarrot comes with:

- Ice Blast
- HotDog Blast.

Comment: awesome! what about the "Storm" ship? I don't see it listed there.

Comment: But are those super weapons so good to be worth it?